# ASP.NET MVC validation. How to work with nested classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a model, which have some properties/classes inside. Now I want to validate something:

```
                <% = Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.Ideas.Title, new { @class = "width_percent_80" }) %>
                <% = Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ideas.Title) %>
```

but it named textbox as Ideas.Title (instead of title). Why?

Answer (score 0):

> but it named textbox as Ideas.Title (instead of title). Why?

So that the default model binder be able to successfully bind to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       // the model was not valid => redisplay the view 
       // so that the user can fix his errors
       return View(model);
   }

   // at this stage validation passed => we can access individual properties
   // of the view model such as model.Ideas.Title here
   ...
}
```

Comment: @user285336, 2 possibilities: modify your view model and include the Title property directly upon the root, or write a custom textbox helper that will do this. The Html.TextBoxFor does what you see.

Answer (score 0):

The nested class will give you a nested field name. But you can add annotation in your entity .cs file to override this.

For example:
in your Ideas.cs file,

```
[Column(name: "title")]              //<- add this
public string Title{ get; set; }
```

Of course, you need to use the DataAnnotation namespace.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```